# Why does perl insert an undef value into my hash?

Tags: perl, hash

Let me start off with a simple minimal example:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

my %hash;
$hash{count} = 4;
$hash{elems}[$_] = {} for (1..$hash{count});

print Dumper \%hash;
```

Here is the result (reformatted):

```
$VAR1 = {
          'count' => 4,
          'elems' => [undef, {}, {}, {}, {}]
        };
```

**I do not understand, why did the first element of `$hash{elems}` become an `undef`?**

---

I know there are probably easier ways to do what I am doing, but I am creating these empty hashes so that I can later do `my $e = $hash{elems}[$i]` and continue to use `$e` to interact with the element, eg continue the horror of nested structures with `$e->{subelems}[0] = 100`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Array indices start at `0` in Perl (and in most programming languages for that matter).

In the 1st iteration of `$hash{elems}[$_] = {} for (1..$hash{count});`, `$_` is `1`, and you thus put `{}` at index `1` of `$hash{elems}`.

Since you didn't put anything at index `0` of `$hash{elems}`, it contains `undef`.

To remedy this, you could use [`push`](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/push) instead of assigning to specific indices:

```
push @{$hash{elems}}, {} for 1 .. $hash{count};
```

`push` adds items at the end of its first argument. Initially, `$hash{elems}` is empty, so the end is the 1st index (`0`).

---

Some tips:

- The parenthesis are not needed in `for (1..$hash{count})`: `for 1 .. $hash{count}` works just as well and looks a bit lighter.
- You could initialize your hash when you declare it:

  ```
   my %hash = (
       count => 4,
       elems => [ map { {} } 1 .. 4 ]
   );
  ```
- Initializing `elems` with an arrayref of hashrefs is often useless, thanks to [autovivification](https://perlmaven.com/autovivification). Simply doing `$hash{elems}[0]{some_key} = 42` will create an arrayref in `$hash{elems}`, a hashref at index `0` in this array, containing the key `some_key` with value `42`.
  In some cases though, your initialization could make sense. For instance, if you want to pass `$hash{elems}` (but not `$hash`) to a function (same thing if you want to pass `$hash{elems}[..]` to a function without passing `$hash{elems}`).

Comment: You could also mention that the entire process is useless, because you do not need to pre-initialize hash references. Auto-vivification handles that.

Comment: @TLP Quite right, yes. I'll edit that in, thanks :)

Comment: I absolutely cannot believe I didn’t realize I was indexing from 1… thanks! Not enough coffee today I guess

Comment: @bp99 I guess you should read my comment too, if you haven't already. There is no value in the operation you are doing.

Comment: @TLP actually, there is kinda some value in initializing the hash, cf the last paragraph of the question. Of course, it's possible to do it the other way around (ie, `my %e = ...; ...; push @{$hash{elems}}, \%e`), but doing `my $e = $hash{elems}[..]; ...` can also make sense... Would need to see more code to judge IMO.

Comment: @TLP sure, but then how can I get a reference to a hash that does not exist yet? I mentioned that I would like to get an element later so that I don’t have to write the entire dereference chain each time I want to manipulate some value deep within the structure. If I initialize a hashref, I can later do eg `my $e = $hash{elems}[2]`. If I do not define the `$hash{elems}[2]`, I don’t know how this could work.

Comment: But you are right, initializing the hash in the first place when declaring will probably be the most concise and readable way to go. Initially, I wanted to fill the hash with values through multiple sub calls hierarchically.

Comment: @bp99 I suppose that could be one value. But its not a very Perlish way. I guess the Perlish way would be to do, inside a block where the scope of `$e` is limited, like a for loop. `my $e = do_stuff(..); push @{ $hash{elems} }, $e;`. Create a structure, then store it in a hash. What you would be doing is `$hash{elems}[0] = {}; my $e = $hash{elems}[0]; $e = do_stuff(..);` Which is to store a structure in a hash, then add to it.